# I send TCP request to HTTP server - but don't have any response

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

Using boost-asio I prepared simple code:

```
asio::io_service io_service;

asio::ip::tcp::socket s(io_service);
asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
asio::connect(s, resolver.resolve({ "aire.pl", "80" }));

cout << "connected" << endl;

string request = "GET http://aire.pl/ HTTP/1.1";
size_t request_length = std::strlen(request.c_str());
asio::write(s, asio::buffer(request, request_length));

cout << "packet sent" << endl;

char reply[1024];
size_t reply_length = asio::read(s, asio::buffer(reply, request_length));
std::cout << "Reply is: ";
std::cout.write(reply, reply_length);
std::cout << "\n";
```

Everything seems to work fine, because using tcp-dump I can see my packets that the program has sent:

[image]

But I don't have any response. The one interesting fact is that, if HTTP server is nginx it works ok! In this example, the HTTP server is Apache2. What's wrong?

Comment: Did you use Wireshark or similar software to check whether you are getting a response at all?

Comment: You would be better off sending an HTTP request, not a TCP request. You haven't, quite. You need `\r\n\r\n` on the end of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't sent a complete HTTP request.  The GET line is followed by optional headers, followed by a blank line to indicate the end of the headers.  Even if you don't want to send any headers, you need to send the blank line so that the server knows it's received the entire request.

Add `\r\n\r\n` to the end of your `request` string.